# Codeigniter: E-Library, Display books with Authors

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good Day Maam/Sir. I need help in Displaying the all the books along with author. Since some books have 1 author I need to display the books along with all authors but it only display 1 author using group by even though the book have 2 or more than authors

[The authors are tom and jerry but it only display tom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94H8H.png)

[Table Authors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEMPy.png)
[Table Books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmcZm.png)

```
public function getbooks()
 {
   return $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_books')
   ->join('tbl_section','tbl_books.section_id=tbl_section.section_id')
   ->join('tbl_authors','tbl_books.book_id=tbl_authors.book_id')
   ->group_by('tbl_authors.book_id')
    ->get()->result_array();

 }
View:
          <tbody>                              
             <?php foreach ($booklists as $value): ?>
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td class="center"><?php echo $value['book_id'] ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $value['book_title'] ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $value['section_name'] ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $value['author_name'].','.$value['author_name'] ?> 
          </td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $value['book_serial'] ?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $value['book_qty'] ?></td>
            <td class="center">

            <a href="<?php echo base_url('Admin/Editbook/'.$value["book_id"]) ?>"><button 
           class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> Edit</button> 
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('Admin/Deletebook/'.$value["book_id"]) ?>">  <button 
           class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remember correctly when you `group_by` author's table `book_id` you will only have one result of book which each of them only have a single author name column. You can use [`group_concat`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/) to append the author names directly.

```
$this->db->select("*, group_concat(author_name separator ', ') as concat_names")
     ....
     ->group_by('tbl_authors.book_id')
     ->get()->result_array();
```

Then you can retrieve the author names using `concat_names` as such:

```
 <td class="center"><?php echo $value['concat_names'] ?></td>
```

Also, mandatory PSA, you should use [htmlspecialchar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to avoid Cross-Site Scripting and issues later on.

```
 <td class="center"><?php echo htmlspecialchar($value['concat_names']) ?></td>
```

Comment: i got this error sir
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN `tbl_section` ON `tbl_books`.`section_id`=`tbl_section`.`section_id` JOI...' at line 2

SELECT *, group_concat(tbl_author.author_name separator JOIN `tbl_section` ON `tbl_books`.`section_id`=`tbl_section`.`section_id` JOIN `tbl_authors` ON `tbl_books`.`book_id`=`tbl_authors`.`book_id` GROUP BY `tbl_authors`.`book_id`

Filename: D:/new xampp/htdocs/elib/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: $this->db->select('*, group_concat(author_name separator ', ') as concat_names')->from('tbl_authors')
  ->join('tbl_section','tbl_books.section_id=tbl_section.section_id')
  ->join('tbl_authors','tbl_books.book_id=tbl_authors.book_id')
     ->group_by('tbl_authors.book_id')
     ->get()->result_array();

Comment: sorry mark, i got the wrong quotes on my first answer. try switching to double quotes for the `->select("*, group_concat(author_name separator ', ') as concat_names") `.

Comment: the error in model is remove now it saying A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: admin/manage_books.php

Line Number: 47

Controller:
$this->load->view('admin/manage_books',$data);

this is my line 47 
my foreach in view
<?php foreach ($booklists as $value): ?>

Comment: huh? ok, hang on a second. could you `var_dump('$booklist');` and see if it returns array?

Comment: The result is Null sir

Comment: this my model looks like now sir    $this->db->select('*,group_concat(author_name separator ", ") as concat_names')->from('tbl_books')
  ->join('tbl_section','tbl_books.section_id=tbl_section.section_id')
  ->join('tbl_authors','tbl_books.book_id=tbl_authors.book_id')
     ->group_by('tbl_authors.book_id')
     ->get()->result_array();

Comment: ok, the null result baffles me. i just tested the query on a new codeigniter installation and got results. even if `tbl_books` is empty, it should return empty array instead of null. i suspect there are changes on your controller that made the `$booklist` not getting passed or set properly.